# Service doesnt refresh array

Tags: angular, service, components

so I have array of objects in service which I fetch from api. I've made method to delete one of the emelements by clicking on button. It works, but in order for site to refresh I need to reload it and it shouldnt be this way. When I send delete request I filter array so that I dont have to fetch array again from API.

```
 deleteCustomer(id: number) {
    this.tokenFromLS = `${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + this.tokenFromLS,
      }),
    };
    this.http
      .delete<void>(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/customer/${id}`, httpOptions)
      .subscribe(()=>
      {
        this.customerList = this.customerList.filter((v) => v.id != id);
      });
  }
```

In my component first I delete resource and then I refresh my array. After deleting it and retriving from Service it should be without element I deleted. When I log size of array it says 0, but when I log elements of array it says that element is there. I am confused of what is happening

```
export class GetCustomerListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private customerService: CustomerServiceService) {}
  customerList: CustomerDto[] = this.customerService.getCustomerList();

  ngOnInit(): void {}
   deleteCustomer(id: number) {
  this.customerService.deleteCustomer(id)
    this.customerList = this.customerService.getCustomerList();
    console.log(this.customerList.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, you should add all the code related to the issue, anyway, you should subscribe to the observable in the consumer (inside ngOnInit in your case) and update the array inside the subscribe callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subscribe from the component itself and not from the service. Service should contain the api logic only.

Just return the httpresponse in the service and subscribe it inside the component.

Comment: Okay I will change it, I have one more question. What if I have 2 components using this service and I want them to communicate. I've seen online that one of methods is using service which has the data thats why I chose this aproach. Should I make one service for api calls and another one that has the data?

Comment: I could not quite understand the last part. Still, if you want to use the same service for multiple components, you can subscribe the same service call on both components. If you want the 2 components to communicate with each other, there are various ways. You could try using Input?Output decorators or observables. Its upto your choice and convenience.